# Parameters to access multiple clusters

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeconfig

I want to access an external k8s cluster which is running in private cloud. Do you have any idea how can I get these parameters? What should I do in order to generate them?

${CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_DATA}
fake-cert-file
fake-key-file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: ${CLUSTER_CA}
    server: ${CLUSTER_ENDPOINT}
  name: ${CLUSTER_NAME}
users:
- name: ${USER}
  user:
    client-certificate-data: $**{CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_DATA}**
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: ${CLUSTER_NAME}
  user:
    client-certificate: **fake-cert-file**
    client-key: **fake-key-file**
  name: ${USER}-${CLUSTER_NAME}
current-context: ${USER}-${CLUSTER_NAME}
```

Answer (score 1):

The steps to allow an access for a "bob" user are the followings:

### Create a new CSR via openssl

`openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout bob-k8s.key -out bob-k8s.csr -subj "/CN=bob/O=devops"`

### Create Kubernetes CertificateSigningRequest object

use
`kubectl create –edit -f k8s-csr.yaml`

and you should input the following

```sh
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: bob-k8s-access
spec:
  groups:
  - system:authenticated
  request: # replace with output from shell command: cat bob-k8s.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n'
  usages:
  - client auth
```

#### Verify your CSR object

`kubectl get csr`

### Approve your certificate

`kubectl certificate approve bob-k8s-access`

#### Verify your Bob's certificate

`kubectl get csr bob-k8s-access -o jsonpath='{.status.certificate}' | base64 --decode > bob-k8s-access.crt`

### Retrieve the cluster CA certificate

`kubectl config view -o jsonpath='{.clusters[0].cluster.certificate-authority-data}' --raw | base64 --decode - > k8s-ca.crt`

### Setup Bob's kubeconfig file

`$ kubectl config set-cluster $(kubectl config view -o jsonpath='{.clusters[0].name}') --server=$(kubectl config view -o jsonpath='{.clusters[0].cluster.server}') --certificate-authority=k8s-ca.crt --kubeconfig=bob-k8s-config --embed-certs`

after this command a `bob-k8s-config` file should be created with Bob's .kube configuration

### Setup Bob's credential accesses

`kubectl config set-credentials bob --client-certificate=bob-k8s-access.crt --client-key=bob-k8s.key --embed-certs --kubeconfig=bob-k8s-config`

### Create a context in your config

`kubectl config set-context bob --cluster=$(kubectl config view -o jsonpath='{.clusters[0].name}') --namespace=<ns-for-bob> --user=bob --kubeconfig=bob-k8s-config`

### Assign roles within the namespace

`kubectl create rolebinding bob-admin --namespace=<ns-for-bob> --clusterrole=admin --user=bob`

For more information about permissions, please, look at the [Kubernetes configuration page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)

---

I've written this instructions starting from [this guide](https://www.openlogic.com/blog/granting-user-access-your-kubernetes-cluster) that is more exhaustive!